# VB.net Form refresh and disable button on close of dialogform

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am developing vb.net application. Where i have a form and click on send mail button opens another form to enter mail details and send mail which has ok and cancel button.

To open form2 below code is used,

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim obj As New Form2
    obj.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub
```

In form1 there is calculate button which should enable only if mail has sent from form2. If user click on cancel button on form2 then calculate button need ro be disabled in form1. Which is not happening. Below is my code,

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click()
        Dim obj As New Form1()
        obj.initinfo(System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

On form1 below code is added

```
Friend Sub initinfo(result As DialogResult)
    If (result = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
        Me.Refresh()
        Me.Activate()
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code has no effect. Please provide some suggestions.

Thanks in advance
Sangeetha

Comment: on which form is `button2` in ? is it in the same form u are generating the code from ? Try adding a `MsgBox("aa")` to see if `result=dialogresult.Cancel` rally fires.If it fires than you need to specify where your button 2 is..e.g : `form1.button2.enabled=false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to disable Button2 on Form1, if Button2 (which I suppose is the Cancel button) on Form2 is pressed.

In the Properties window:

Set your cancel button property `Form2.Button2.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel`
Set the positive response button (let's say Button1) property `Button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`

Let Form2 know which is which:

```
Form2.AcceptButton = Button1
Form2.CancelButton = Button2
```

in Form1, evaluate the response using the Form.DialogResult property:
(enclose in a Using block to properly Dispose() of the object you created)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Using obj As New Form2
        obj.ShowDialog(Me)

        If obj.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
           Me.Button2.Enabled = False
        End If
   End Using
End Sub
```

Another way.
Create a custom result property on Form2 and check its status when the Form closes.

```
Class Form2
    (...)
    Public Property UserChoice As Boolean
    (...)

    Private Sub Button1_Click()
        Me.UserChoice = True
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click()
        Me.UserChoice = False
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    (...)
End Class
```

In Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Using obj As New Form2
        obj.ShowDialog(Me)

        If obj.UserChoice = False Then
           Me.Button2.Enabled = False
        End If

        'Or -> 
        Me.Button2.Enabled = obj.UserChoice
   End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of Form1 on Form2, this new instance is not referring to the original form, but creating a new form.

Following are the correct steps:

1.Create a property for the Button on Form1.

```
Public ReadOnly Property BtnSubmit As Button
    Get
        Return button1
    End Get
End Property
```

2.Create a property for the Form1 in Form2.

```
Public Property Form1Instance As Form1
    Get
    End Get
    Set
    End Set
End Property
```

3.Now while instantiating form2, pass `Me` as reference in Form1Instance property

```
Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim f2 As Form2 = New Form2
    f2.Form1Instance = Me
    f2.Show
End Sub
```

4.On Form2, use like this:

```
If (Not (Form1Instance) Is Nothing) Then
   Form1Instance.BtnSubmit.Enabled = false
End If
```

In your case it will be:

```
Form1Instance.initinfo(System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
```

I hope you get the idea.